# POST method is not supported for this route

Tags: laravel

First, I've checked other question topic, but couldn't find the solution.

when I try to post my form. I am getting this error.

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   GET, HEAD.

**Form:**

```
<div class="card-body">
    <form action="{{route('profile.update', ['id' => $id])}}" method="post">
      @csrf
      @put

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="location">Location</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="location" value="{{$info->location}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="about">About</label>
            <textarea name="about" id="about" rows="10" cols="50" class="form-control">{{$info->about}}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <p class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit">Update Your Info</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(["middleware" => "auth"], function(){
    route::get("/profile/edit", [
        "uses" => "ProfilesController@edit",
        "as" => "profile.edit"
    ]);
    route::get("/profile/{slug}", [
        "uses" => "ProfilesController@index",
        "as" => "profile"
    ]);
    route::put("/profile/update/{id}", [
        "uses" => "ProfilesController@update",
        "as" => "profile.update"
    ]);
});
```

in controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    dd($request->all());

}
```

Comment: since you are not using resource route that is why you should remove this `{{ method_field('PUT') }}`  from your form

Comment: As for REST conventions, `put` http verb is to be used when updating a resource

Comment: @parabellum are you trying to update an existing resource?

Comment: @parabellum I updated my awnser

Comment: @AdityaThakur I am trying to update profile table in DB

Comment: @parabellum check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, i can understand that you're trying to update a profile using POST method or may be PUT method earlier. Since, the resource you are editing is unique, you're not passing any parameters for the controller to find that single resource so as to update it.

therefore modify your your route like

```
 route::put("/profile/update/{id}", [
        "uses" => "ProfilesController@update",
        "as" => "profile.update"
    ]);
```

And your form like

```
<form action="{{route('profile.update', ['id' => $id])}}" method="post">
@csrf
@method('put')
```

You'll need to pass the ID of the profile you want to update as parameter

then at the controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
 //edit the profile with id = $id
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it says this: `Undefined variable: id (View: /var/www/realestate/resources/views/profiles/edit.blade.php)` also I added in the question controller too at the bottom

Comment: @parabellum Thats because `$id` i entered is just mock id,  you'll need to pass the id of the profile you are editing, you are getting profile data in your view right, in your case id should be something like `$info->id`,

Comment: oh sorry, that was my mistake I fixed it. but it still giving that method error

Comment: can you comment the method with  `route::get("/profile/{slug}")`, and then check

Comment: why, if I comment out that route I cant access the page?

Comment: don't worry about it, its for debugging purpose

Comment: @parabellum also replace `@put` with `@method('put')`

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your form definition

```
 <form class="{{route('profile.update', ['id' => $id])}}" method="post">
```

should be

```
 <form action="{{route('profile.update', ['id' => $id])}}" method="post">
```

Comment: wow big syntax.. okay, it's not working.. error is `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.`

Comment: @parabellum change `@put` to `@method('put')`, my bad

Comment: @AdityaThakur yes that change solved the problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you made a form for `PUT` request, you have to change

```
route::post("/profile/update/profile", [
    "uses" => "ProfilesController@update",
    "as" => "profile.update"
]);
```

to this

```
route::put("/profile/update/profile", [
    "uses" => "ProfilesController@update",
    "as" => "profile.update"
]);
```

Comment: thank you but,  if it this easy to solve I wouldn't ask the question :) no effect...

Comment: well, check my other answer, it's easier than this :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correction in your provided example.

In form `route('profile.update', ['id' => {here you have to place id of record which you want to update}])`.

**View File**
    
         $info->id])}}" method="post">

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="location">Location</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="location" value="{{$info->location}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="about">About</label>
            <textarea name="about" id="about" rows="10" cols="50" class="form-control">{{$info->about}}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <p class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit">Update Your Info</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**In Route**

```
Route::group(["middleware" => "auth"], function(){
    route::get("/profile/{slug}", [
        "uses" => "ProfilesController@index",
        "as" => "profile"
    ]);
    route::get("/profile/edit/profile", [
        "uses" => "ProfilesController@edit",
        "as" => "profile.edit"
    ]);
    route::post("/profile/update/profile/{id}", [
        "uses" => "ProfilesController@update",
        "as" => "profile.update"
    ]);
});
```

**In Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    dd($id, $request->all());
}
```

Comment: you removed `method_field('PUT')` from the form. it will only work if you will add method

Comment: updated the question with POST error not put and codes too

Comment: I put the input hidden bottom of the form and tried with that but still same error.

Comment: @parabellum check now. I updated your code with corrections.